# Using storybook with react-rails?

Tags: react-rails, storybook

I am trying to use storybook with `react-rails`

If I install the reactjs project inside `app/assets/javascripts/components` I will have so many other files not related directly to the project ( stories and node_modules.. etc)

Whats is the recommended way to use storybook with a `react-rails` ?
Also, creating a reactjs inside `app/assets/javascripts/components` will make it overhead, considering that I am already using `react-rails`

What's the advice here?

Comment: What have you tried and what issues have you run into?

Stack Overflow is not good at these open-ended question types (as you can see by lack of answer here.

Comment: I ran into this question when trying to accomplish the same thing. I have a repository that works, however it doesn't necessarily address all of your questions regarding the overhead involved. The repo that I created is here: https://github.com/rdgco/react-rails-storybook